# How to populate RichTextBox from a saved value?

Tags: richtextbox

I have RichTextBox. I saved RichTextBox.Rtf on a database.
How I should I populate RichBoxText from the saved .Rtf value?

When move saved value to RichBoxText.Text - I see there all format codes.
When I use:
 RichBoxText.Rtf.Insert(0, a.info_text) ;
all data disappears - only format codes are moved.

Thanks,

Zalek

Comment: It would just be RichBoxText.Rtf = value.  It's unclear what `a.info_text` is in your post.

Comment: Please disregard my question. Suddnly my code is working today.

Comment: Then click on the "delete" link above.  The question won't help other people.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found what a problem was.
I have a database where I saved some data as text from a TextBox.
Now I decided to convert my application to use RichTextBox instead of TextBox.
Each time a data was saved from a TextBox, I was getting a run time error trying to move it to RichTextBox.rtf. When saved data was from RichTextBox - it worked.
So what I need to do is to converts the database fields from text to .rtf format - I found examples on the web how to do it.
Problem solved.

Zalek